# How to use ant with antlr3

Tags: eclipse, ant, antlr, antlr3

My question is about using ANT with ANTLR3.

I downloaded the ant-antlr3 and put it in the directory

```
eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib
```

In my build.xml put:

```
`<path id="classpath">
     <pathelement location="${lib}/antlr-3.4-complete.jar"/>
     <pathelement location="${lib}/ant-antlr3.jar"/>
 </ path>`

   `<target name="antlr" depends="init">
   <antlr: ant-antlr3 xmlns: antlr = "antlib: org / apache / tools / ant / antlr"
    target = "$ {Analyzers} / AnalizadorLexer.g"
    outputdirectory = "$ {AnalizadoresBuild}"
    verbose = "true">
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
   </ antlr: ant-antlr3>
</ target>`
```

Running the antlr target gets this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C: \ Users \ melmar \ Documents \ workspace \ PL \ Prac12 \ build_pol.xml: 68: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib: org / apache / tools / ant / antlr: ant-antlr3
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check That any custom tasks / types Have Been declared.
Action: Check That any <presetdef> / declarations have taken place <macrodef>.
No types or tasks Have Been In This namespace defined yet
This appears to be an antlib declaration.
Action: Check That the Implementing library exists in one of:

         -C: \ Users \ melmar \. Ant \ lib (don´t exist)
         -a directory added on the command line argument With The-lib
```

Will you please anyone knows what to do?, Did not find the ant-antlr3 in classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the `antlr` task, but simply put the ANTLR JAR into `libs` and then do something like this:

```xml
<path id="classpath">

    <!-- more entries here -->

    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="generate">
    <echo>generating the parser and lexer</echo>
    <java classname="org.antlr.Tool" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-fo" />
        <arg value="path/to/output/generated/files" />
        <arg value="path/to/Grammar.g" />
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: I do the same, but I also have it set to automatically download the ANTLR tool into the lib folder during the build if it's not already there (or out of date) so I don't have to keep the library in source control.

Comment: Example `build.xml`, including auto-download and complete up-to-date checks: https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/build.xml

Comment: @280Z28, that's a neat idea. "Ant-a-la-Maven", so to say :)